# "Create Local Variable" as a means of resolving references in PyCharm and Intellij for Python

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, pycharm

Is there a shorcut for creating a new variable that is highlighted with red curvy line ("unresolved reference") in Intellij for Python or PyCharm like there's in IntelliJ for Java.
Tried to find the answer in [Resolving References](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/resolving-references.html) without success.
Is there's some language specific constraint which explains the lack of this feature for Python?